# Close to JFrame window

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a **JFrame** which I want to press the "X" key (close the **JFrame**) to confirm if I really want to close the application or not. If I click "NO", it closes the application.

Why doesn't it work if I select "NO"?

```
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt){
            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Confirm out?", 
                    "AppLocal", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE){
                dispose();
            }
        }
    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV9MT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yowxI.png)

Comment: Should you compare against YES_OPTION?

Comment: @GhostCat If i press "Yes_Option", the programa closes.

Comment: *I just tested your code and it doesn't work for me. The same thing happens.* - Post your [mre]. So you need to post demo code with an empty JFrame and your WindowListener. I always like to set a variable to contain the result of the confirm dialog. That way you can display the return value to make sure it is what you expect. See: [Closing an Application](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for an example of how I would write the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method:
`int javax.swing.JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int optionType) throws HeadlessException`

In **optionType** parameter, you have to use:

- `JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION`
- `JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION`
- `JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION`

The available return values are:

```java
    //
    // Return values.
    //
    /** Return value from class method if YES is chosen. */
    public static final int         YES_OPTION = 0;
    /** Return value from class method if NO is chosen. */
    public static final int         NO_OPTION = 1;
    /** Return value from class method if CANCEL is chosen. */
    public static final int         CANCEL_OPTION = 2;
    /** Return value form class method if OK is chosen. */
    public static final int         OK_OPTION = 0;
    /** Return value from class method if user closes window without selecting
     * anything, more than likely this should be treated as either a
     * <code>CANCEL_OPTION</code> or <code>NO_OPTION</code>. */
    public static final int         CLOSED_OPTION = -1;
```

So, your code can be:

```java
setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
        if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Confirm out?", 
            "AppLocal", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION
        ) {
            dispose();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've been able to solve the problem.